# Enums of typealiases in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, enums

I'm clearly missing something basic about how `enums` work in Swift. Consider the following scenario:

```
typealias State = String

enum MyStates : State {
    case Start, Working, Done
}
```

I now want to have a function that does stuff with `State`s (e.g. as part of a state machine, etc.):

```
func doSomething(s: State) {
    print("I got \(s)!")
}
```

Seems to me that I ought to be able to call this like so:

```
doSomething(MyStates.Start)
```

However, this fails with the following error: `Cannot convert value of type 'MyStates' to expected argument type 'State' (aka 'String')`

I am perplexed. Seems to me that by declaring `MyStates` as being of type `State`, a `MyState` instance should have a *is-a* relationship with `State`, and so this should work. What am I missing?

Comment: You just need to add MyStates.Start.rawValue. It'll work fine then.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MyState` is the enum type, `State` (aka `String`) the raw type of the enum.

Either you have to pass the raw value

```
typealias State = String

enum MyStates : State {
  case Start, Working, Done
}

func doSomething(s: State) {
  print("I got \(s)!")
}

doSomething(MyStates.Start.rawValue)
```

or the usual way

```
enum MyStates : String {
  case Start, Working, Done
}

func doSomething(s: MyStates) {
  print("I got \(s)!")
}

doSomething(MyStates.Start)
```

Comment: Huh. So, members of the `MyStates` enum are not implicitly also `States` and therefore `Strings`? My problem with the "usual way" you suggest is that I plan on re-using my generic state machine code for other States, not just whatever ones I happen to have set up in the `MyStates` enum.

Thanks for the reply, BTW!

Comment: In digging further, I ended up going down a bit of a rabbit hole that led me to learning about Protocols-with-associated-types, in which I discovered that Swift and Objective-C have totally different semantics surrounding the word "Protocol", and my "is-a" instinct is not correct in Swift-land. 

I still don't have a solution I'm happy with, but at least I mostly understand why what I was trying to do doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly if I correctly answer your question,

but as your title say, for having an "Enums of typealiases in Swift" you could do something like this:

```
enum States {
    typealias Start = Api.Objects.Tasks.States.Start
    typealias Working = Api.Objects.Tasks.States.Working
    typealias Done = Api.Objects.Tasks.States.Done
}
```

And then you can refer to a specific state for example `States.Start` instead of `Api.Objects.Tasks.States.Start`.